# How to do 3D Gaussian filtering in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I have a multidimension matrix and I want to do Gaussian smoothing not only in 2D along `x` and `y`, but I also want to do smoothing across the channels in 3D.  How can I do that in OpenCV?

I know there is a function called **GaussianBlur** which can apply a Gaussian filter in 2D, but how about 3D? The way you can call this looks something like below:

```
GaussianBlur(frame, frame2, Size(sigma, sigma), 0, 0);
```

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag as there is no reference to it at all in your post.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate, the answer to the linked question doesn't describe how to do this in OpenCV, and it certainly doesn't address using the channels as the third dimensions. There is a good way to do this in OpenCV, and I will provide an answer later, if someone hasn't already done so.

Comment: @B... - I thought it did, but my apologies if it actually didn't.  Also, I would like to see your answer as I'm curious on how you'd do this in OpenCV myself.

Comment: Even though this question is not a duplicate (the linked question is for MATLAB, not for OpenCV), it has not been reopened because the authoritative answer to this question is simply "no, OpenCV has no support for 3D filtering of any kind". (In that case, it duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020438/opencv-gaussian-blur-smoothing-of-3d-matrix-histogram, which is likewise also closed.) However, should the situation ever change in OpenCV, similar questions should point to OpenCV documentation, to avoid misleading future visitors with obsolete answers.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported off of OpenCV natively.  However, because Gaussian filtering is separable, you can filter each dimension separately.

Use a combination of `BaseRowFilter`: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#BaseRowFilter and `BaseColumnFilter`: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#BaseColumnFilter and specify the Gaussian kernels as 1D.

Use `getGaussianKernel`: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gauss#getgaussiankernel to help you compute a 1D Gaussian kernel without having to do this yourself.

Now, for the third dimension, this is going to be tricky.  You'll have to apply individual row / column filters to each 3D slice at a particular spatial location.  For example, if you had a volume of 5 slices, and the size of one image was 10 x 10, the final filtered result in 3D is you having to extract 100 1D signals of size 5, then apply the kernel on each of these 1D signals separately.

Take a look at this post for more insight: [How to do a Gaussian filtering in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814187/how-to-do-a-gaussian-filtering-in-3d) .  Someone else has tried to do this in the past.

Good luck!

Comment: Your approach seems promising @rayryeng. But before I try to implement this, does `BaseRowFilter` and `BaseColumnFilter` assume the `src` to be 2D array? Is it straightword to convert it to have 3D array as input? Any hints will be appreciated